# Форма отправляется даже при return false

Tags: javascript, html, submit

```html
<form id="buy" class="m1-form" action="order.php" method="post"
  onsubmit="if(this.name.value==''){alert('Введите Ваше имя!');return false}if(this.phone.value=='' ||  this.phone.value.length < 13){alert('Введите Ваш номер телефона!');return false}return true;">
  <input class="field" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Введите ваше имя" required>
  <input class="field ea_phone" name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Введите ваш телефон" required>
  <button class="button-m">сделать заказ</button>
</form>
```

вот весь код. Никаких других функций нет, alert высвечивается но форма подтверждается и перекидывает на другую страницу

Comment: причина - в коде, не включенном в вопрос

Comment: *alert высвечивается но форма подтверждается и перекидывает на другую страницу* - вовсе нет. Какое у Вас средство просмотра и версия ?

Comment: @Alex последняя версия хрома, но думаю во всех браузерах будет так же